# It asks for id and asks for name and then shows exception saying error in MySql syntax...how do i resolve?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have tried Both ways for the queryUpdate, it shows the same exception.

String queryUpdate = "update student set name = '?' where id = '?' ";

String queryUpdate = "update student set name = ? where id = ? ";

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class UpdateRecord 
{
private Connection connection;
Statement statement;
String queryUpdate = "update student set name = ? where id = ? ";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public UpdateRecord()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = CreateConnection.getDatabase();    // creating connection from the class we created in the file CreateConnection.java

        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        System.out.println("Enter id...");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter name...");
        String name = buffer.readLine();

        statement.executeUpdate(query);

        System.out.println("\n\n\t\t!!!.........UPDATED..........!!!");

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException s)
    {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException i)
    {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new UpdateRecord();
}
}
```

MySql Exception:

Class Loaded
Connection Created
Enter id...
1
Enter name...
Hamid
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? where id = ?' at line 1**
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1564)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1485)
    at UpdateRecord.(UpdateRecord.java:34)
    at UpdateRecord.main(UpdateRecord.java:56)

Comment: You are not creating any object of query anywhere, once you create the Query object you have to set the parameters and then you fire the executeUpdate method.

Comment: Use the tutorial Luke: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to use *prepared* statements with positional parameters.  A good choice, but your syntax has some problems.

First, the following line will need to change:

```
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()` does not take any parameters.  Always check the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) for a possible mistake you may have made.

Also, you never assigned the positional parameters.  Try the following full code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement statement;
connection = CreateConnection.getDatabase();
statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

System.out.println("Enter id...");
int id = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());

System.out.println("Enter name...");
String name = buffer.readLine();

statement.setString(1, name);
statement.setInt(2, id);

statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: To be able to do that, variable `statement` must be changed to `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Andreas So many problems with the code, I posted way too fast.